# I can't upload base64 image file to IPFS using Pinata in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, filestream

I am gonna upload multiple images to IPFS using Pinata cloud. Images are extracted using video-thumb-generator module. If I select only one file by dragging-drop, there's no error. However, uploading those images extracted by video-thumb-generator module with axios, there's Invalid Request Format 400 error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72gBX.png)

```
export const MintPage = () => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState([]);
  const [myipfsHash, setIPFSHASH] = useState("");

  const pinFileToPinata = async (fileToHandle) => {
    try {
      console.log("starting", fileToHandle);

      // initialize the form data
      const formData = new FormData();

      // append the file form data to
      formData.append("file", fileToHandle);

      // call the keys from .env

      const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
      const API_SECRET = process.env.REACT_APP_API_SECRET;

      // the endpoint needed to upload the file
      const url = `https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS`;

      const response = await axios.post(url, formData, {
        maxContentLength: "Infinity",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          pinata_api_key: API_KEY,
          pinata_secret_api_key: API_SECRET,
        },
      });

      console.log(response);

      // get the hash
      setIPFSHASH(response.data.IpfsHash);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const handleVideoUpload = (event) => {
    const video = event.target.files[0];
    const videoToThumb = new VideoToThumb(video)
      .load()
      .positions([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]) // time
      .xy([0, 0]) // coordinator
      .size([200, 200]) // image size
      .type("base64")
      .error(function (err) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
      })
      .done(async function (imgs) {
        imgs.forEach(function (img) {
          var elem = new Image();
          elem.src = img;

          document.body.appendChild(elem);
        });

        setFile(imgs);
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <Button
          component="label"
          variant="contained"
          startIcon={<CloudUploadIcon />}
          style={{
            textTransform: "capitalize",
            marginTop: "30px",
            marginBottom: "30px",
          }}
        >
          Select file
          <VisuallyHiddenInput type="file" onChange={handleVideoUpload} />
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          onClick={() => {
            file.forEach((img) => {
              pinFileToPinata(img);
            });
          }}
          style={{
            textTransform: "capitalize",
            marginTop: "30px",
            marginBottom: "30px",
            marginLeft: "30px",
          }}
        >
          Pin To Cloud
        </Button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Please help me.

I tried googling for 12 hours but there's no satisfied result.